# Xcode can't find Bridging header when loading Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, bridging-header

I am creating a Framework (compiled Library), which has both Swift and Objective C code so I create a bridging header inside my Framework project.
The Framework builds fine and the Bridging header has no issues.

However when I drag the product .sdk into my demo project to test importing the Framework, I get the error

```
Failed to import bridging header "...LibraryName-Bridging-Header.h"
```

I added multiple paths to the Search Paths without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frameworks with mixed Swift and Objective-C code do not need (and should not have) a bridging header.

First make sure that your framework's build settings includes "Defines Module: Yes".

Then, your framework should already have an umbrella header, this is the header with the same name as your framework with stuff like this in it

```
//! Project version number for MyFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyFrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for MyFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyFrameworkVersionString[];
```

Any Objective-C stuff that you want to be visible to Swift needs a header with public membership which is imported into that umbrella header like this `#import <MyFramework/MyHeaderName.h>`. Note that you need to apply this rule recursively: if you import an Objective-C header in the umbrella header, anything *it* imports also needs to be public and in the umbrella header.

This can be a little tricky if some of your Objective-C headers have unnecessary imports, or import stuff that you don't want to be public in your framework. You may need to restructure you code a bit so that you have a clear separation between public and private headers.

If you do that, all of that public Objective-C code should be automatically usable in the framework's Swift code, without any bridging header.

Official docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift

Comment: Thank you for the response. My Objective C code will not use any Swift code, just the other way around. I found the umbrella header with the two lines only you describe above. Do I import the bridging header there , or individually the files I had on my bridging header. Tried different variations without any luck. The moment I removed the link to the bridging header from Build Settings I get "out of scope" error on my Swift code trying to reach the Objective C classes.

Comment: @PoolHallJunkie again, you should not have any bridging header. Put the individual imports of your bridging header in that umbrella header, using the `<...>` notation in my answer.

Comment: Thats what I tried but I get error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module ". Build settings for allow non-modular is YES and umbrella header is public

Comment: Changed the imports to "Tools.h" in my umbrella file and added them with full path "ProjectName/Tools.h" inside the individual  objective-c header files. That worked ! thank you